# Command substitution for (GNU coreutils) date in gawk gensub

Tags: bash, awk, command-substitution

I have a data file with lines containing a huge amount (~ 5K) of dates in format `yy-dd-mm`.

A tipical file line could be:

```
bla bla 21-04-26 blabla blabla 18-01-28 bla bla bla bla 19-01-12 blabla
```

I need to do this kind of replacement for any single date:

```
$ date --date="18-01-28" "+%A, %d %B %Y"
Sunday, 28 January 2018
```

I already solved this problem using sed (see the post scriptum for details).

I would like to use gawk, instead.
I came up with this command:

```
$ gawk '{b = gensub(/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/,"$(date --date=\"\\1\" \"+%A, %d %B %Y\")", "g")}; {print b}'
```

**The problem** is that bash does not expand the date command inside gensub, in fact I obtain:

```
$ echo "bla bla 21-04-26 blabla blabla 18-01-28 bla bla bla bla 19-01-12 blabla" | gawk '{b = gensub(/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/,"$(date --date=\"\\1\" \"+%A, %d %B %Y\")", "g")}; {print b}' 
bla bla $(date --date="21-04-26" "+%A, %d %B %Y") blabla blabla $(date --date="18-01-28" "+%A, %d %B %Y") bla bla bla bla $(date --date="19-01-12" "+%A, %d %B %Y") blabla
```

I do not get how I could modify the gawk command to obtain the desired result:

```
bla bla Monday, 26 April 2021 blabla blabla Sunday, 28 January 2018 bla bla bla bla Saturday, 12 January 2019 blabla
```

**post scriptum:**

For what concerns sed, I solved with this script

```
#!/bin/bash

#pathFile hard-coded here
pathFile='./data.txt'

#treshold to avoid "to many arguments" error with sed
maxCount=1000
counter=0

#list of dates in the data file
dateList=($(egrep -o "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" "$pathFile" | sort | uniq))

#string to pass multiple instruction to sed
sedCommand=''

for item in ${dateList[@]}
do
    sedCommand+="s/"$item"/"$(date --date="$item" "+%A, %d %B %Y")"/g;"
    (( counter++ ))
    if [[ $counter -gt $maxCount ]]
    then
        sed -i "$sedCommand" "$pathFile"
        counter=0
        sedCommand=''
    fi
done
[[ ! -z "$sedCommand" ]] && sed -i "$sedCommand" "$pathFile"
```

Comment: `command substitution` is a shell term. awk is not shell. You wouldn't talk about command substitution in C, you'd just talk about calling a function and saving it's output, and you can't call a shell command directly from C. Exactly the same is true of awk. Just like in C, in awk you can call awk functions, and there are ways (e.g. `system("date")`) to call external commands like Unix date, but you can't just call those external commands directly and when you do it's not called "command substitution" it's called "calling an external command".

Comment: @EdMorton I understand your point. I was talking about the command substitution of date inside gensub though.

Comment: My point was that since command substitution is a shell term/concept there is no command substitution of date inside gensub or command substitution of any other command anywhere else in an awk script though. From awk you spawn a shell to call a command, but the result of that command doesn't then replace the command somehow like it does in a shell if you use command substitution - you have to manually read the output of the command.

Comment: Using command substitution in shell to set `foo` to the output of some command `cmd` is `foo=$(cmd)` but the shell equivalent of what we do in awk or C to get the output of the command is more equivalent to `foo=''; while IFS= read -r line; foo="$foo"$'\n'"$line"; done < <(cmd)`, i.e. it is not similar to command substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gawk has builtin functions to deal with date/time which would be MUCH faster compared to invoking the external `date` command.

#### Example input:

```
# cat file
79-03-21 | 21-01-01
79-04-17 | 20-12-31
```

#### The gawk script:

```
# cat date.awk
{
    while (match($0, /([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})/, arr) ) {
        date = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
        #                           \_YY    \_MM    \_DD
        if (arr[1] >= 70) {
            time = sprintf("19%s %s %s  1  0  0", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
            #               YYYY MM DD HH MM SS
        } else {
            time = sprintf("20%s %s %s  1  0  0", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])
        }
        secs = mktime(time)
        new_date = strftime("%A, %d %B %Y", secs)
        $0 = gensub(date, new_date, "g")
    }
    print
}
```

#### Result:

```
# gawk -f date.awk file
Wednesday, 21 March 1979 | Friday, 01 January 2021
Tuesday, 17 April 1979 | Thursday, 31 December 2020
```

Comment: You could just do `year = (arr[1] < 70 ? 20 : 19) arr[1]` and then have 1 call to sprintf using that instead of 2 almost identical calls to sprintf. Why pick a year of "70" to separate the century at all though? There's no indication that `70` in the data means 1970 instead of 2070 so I think that's overcomplicating things and may be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: `date = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", arr[1], arr[2], arr[3])` can just be `date=arr[0]`, and `$0 = gensub(date, new_date, "g")` can just be `gsub(date, new_date)`

Comment: @EdMorton also GNU date makes a similar assumption about the limit, with 69 as treshold. I decided to set a treshold as a parameter inside the script.

Answer (score 3):

Just to show how to do "command substitution" using awk's pipes —

```
$ cat foo.awk
{
    while (match($0, /([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/, arr) ) {
        date = arr[1]
        cmd = "date -d " date " +'%A, %d %B %Y' "
        cmd | getline new_date
        # pipes are not closed automatically!
        close(cmd)
        $0 = gensub(date, new_date, "g")
    }
    print
}
$ cat file
79-03-21 | 21-01-01
79-04-17 | 20-12-31
$ gawk -f foo.awk file
Wednesday, 21 March 1979 | Friday, 01 January 2021
Tuesday, 17 April 1979 | Thursday, 31 December 2020
```

Comment: thank you, I was about to ask if you could also show something about command substitution. By the way, your first answer completely address the problem.

Comment: If that call to getline failed you'd end up with a repeat of the previously valid date in the output with no indication whatsoever that there was an issue. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to call getline. You're also passing input data (`arr[1]`) unquoted to the shell which will probably not really cause any problems this time given it has to be a pair of digits but you should really be quoting it like you should all strings in shell - `cmd = "date -d '" date "' +'%A, %d %B %Y'"`.

Comment: Also if you use `\047` instead of `'` throughout your script then you can call it from the command line (or inline in a shell script) instead of requiring it to be in a separate awk script file.